# Deletion of multiple(more than one node) nodes at a time from the CRXDE lite or CRX Explorer

Tags: aem

How can we delete multiple(more than one node) nodes at a time from the CRXDE lite or CRX Explorer

- `http://host:port/crx/de/index.jsp`
  or from
- `http://host:port/crx/explorer/browser/index.jsp`

Path:: /content/path to my web page parsys/

Where as the keyboard Ctrl or Shift keys are not allowing for selection & deletion of multiple nodes at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I tried but it seems that there is no way to delete multiple nodes at a time using **CRXDE Lite** or **CRX Explorer**!

However, if the nodes, which you want to delete, are type of ***page*** or ***asset***, you can delete multiple at the same time using `http://localhost:4502/siteadmin#/content` or `http://localhost:4502/damadmin#/content/dam` correspondingly!

Comment: This is the Sling way to do it: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#deleting-multiple-items

The star character (`*`) stands for multiple children:

`curl -F":operation=delete" -F":applyTo=/content/*" http://host/content/sample`.

You can also explicitly specify a list of nodes to delete: `curl -F":operation=delete" -F":applyTo=/content/page1" \    
    -F":applyTo=/content/page2" http://host/content/sample`

Answer (score 1):

try to login using Webdav and then then you can delete multiple nodes at one time. To access CRX repository using Webdav, you need to use Webdav client. For example you can download "AnyClient" for free.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if CRXDE Lite allows to select multiple nodes using CRTL or SHIFT keys.

But if you already know the paths of the nodes or pages you want to delete. I prefer using the following curl command instead of using CRXDE Lite -

```
curl -X DELETE http://host:port/content-path/jcr:content/nodeName -u admin:admin
```

Hope this helps you.